# Can't monitor CPU temperature using lm-sensors

Tags: drivers, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

I installed `lm-senosrs` and ran `sudo sensors-detect`. Here is what I get:

```
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z390 GAMING X [Default string]
# Board: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z390 GAMING X-CF
# Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz (6/158/12)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8688
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): yes
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:a323 at 0000:00:1f.4.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 1:00.0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 2 at 1:00.0 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 4 at 1:00.0 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at 1:00.0 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at 1:00.0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at 1:00.0 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 9 at 1:00.0 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

When I run `sensors` I get:

```
No sensors found!
Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.
Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.
```

I tried to reboot but it didn't help. Also running `/etc/init.d/kmod start` didn't help.

I tried `psensors` but it seems that it cannot see CPU core temperatures. I also tried reading the temperature using a `Python` library called `psutil` but it cannot see the CPU too.

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensors_temperatures()
{'acpitz': [shwtemp(label='', current=16.8, high=18.8, critical=18.8), shwtemp(label='', current=27.8, high=119.0, critical=119.0)]}
```

I also tried to comment out `blacklist i2c_i801` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and reboot but with no benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because `coretemp` wasn't installed properly for my current kernel.

```
$ locate coretemp
/home/admin1/Downloads/linux-hwe-5.3.0/Documentation/hwmon/coretemp.rst
/home/admin1/Downloads/linux-hwe-5.3.0/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.c
/lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko
/lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic/include/config/sensors/coretemp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-42-generic/include/config/sensors/coretemp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-53-generic/include/config/sensors/coretemp.h
```

I didn't find `coretemp.ko` for my current kernel `5.3.0-42`. So I switched to `5.3.0-40` using the instructions in https://meetrix.io/blog/aws/changing-default-ubuntu-kernel.html

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-"your.kernel.here"-generic
```

Replace `"your.kernel.here"` with your kernel's version without the quotes.

Comment: `uname -r` prints your kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was simply that you have to run `sudo /etc/init.d/kmod start`. But `sensors-detect` didn't say anything about `sudo`.